# Entity repsoitory/service pattern, where to put functionality that needs 2 or more services

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity, repository-pattern

I have created a generic repository for my entity types which handles retrieving , adding and deleting data. Each entity type has a corresponding Service class which interacts with the generic repository to handle all the Data access.

However many times i need to retrieve data based on more than one service and i am never sure where to place this code. For example below is some code that returns a list of email addresses ("GetEmailTrackingAddressGroup" function) which is using 3 different service. I have placed this in the "GroupService" but it could also easily go in the "UserService" aswell.

```
 public class GroupService
{
    IRepository<Group> groupRepository;

    public GroupService(IRepository<Group> groupRepository)
    {
        this.groupRepository = groupRepository;
    }

    public Group GetById(int id)
    {
        return groupRepository.GetSingle(g => g.Id == id); 
    }

     public static List<string> GetEmailTrackingAddressesGroup(int instanceId, int groupId)
    {

        MyEntities entityContext = new MyEntities();

        UserGroupService userGroupService =
         new UserGroupService(new BaseRepoistory<UserGroup>(entityContext ));


        UserService userService =
         new UserService(new BaseRepoistory<User>(entityContext ));

        List<string> emails = new List<string>();

        Group productGroup = GetById(groupId);

        foreach (UserGroup userGroup in userGroupService.GetByGroupId(productGroup.Id))
        {
            if (userGroup.EmailTracking)
                emails.Add(userService.GetByUserId(userGroup.UserId).UserName);
        }

        return emails;
    }
}
```

My Question is, should you just try and pick the most relevant service and place the code in there and call the other relevant service inside it, or should i create a new class which handles Data access when more than 1 service is involved. For example i have placed code for what this class might look like below.

```
 public class DataFunctions
{

     public static List<string> GetEmailTrackingAddressesGroup(int instanceId, int groupId)
    {
        MyEntities entityContext = new MyEntities();

        GroupService userGroupService =
         new GroupService(new BaseRepoistory<Group>(entityContext ));

        UserGroupService userGroupService =
         new UserGroupService(new BaseRepoistory<UserGroup>(entityContext ));

        UserService userService =
         new UserService(new BaseRepoistory<User>(entityContext ));

        List<string> emails = new List<string>();

        Group productGroup = GetById(groupId);

        foreach (UserGroup userGroup in userGroupService.GetByGroupId(productGroup.Id))
        {
            if (userGroup.EmailTracking)
                emails.Add(userService.GetByUserId(userGroup.UserId).UserName);
        }

        return emails;
    }
}
```

The second approach seems to make more sense as this means each service will never rely on other services however im not sure if i am going about this the right way. One concern i have about using this separate class is that it will get very big and hard to manage.

**Edit -** For now i have come up with a third solution, i think it is better than my previous two however i'm still uncertain if i am managing this correctly. I have created a seperate "EmailService" which will handle all data queries which are needed when handing email functionality in my main ASP.Net web project.

Below is the code for this new class

```
  //Functionality realting to data needed when handling emails
public class EmailService
{
    MyEntities entityContext;

    AspUserService aspUserService;
    GroupService groupService;
    UserGroupService userGroupService;

    public EmailService()
    {
        entityContext = new MyEntities ();

        aspUserService = new AspUserService(new RepositoryBase<aspnet_Users>(entityContext));
        groupService = new GroupService(new RepositoryBase<Group>(entityContext));
        userGroupService = new UserGroupService(new RepositoryBase<UserGroup>(entityContext));
    }

    public List<string> GetEmailsForProductGroup(int groupId)
    {
        List<string> emails = new List<string>();

        Group productGroup = groupService.GetById(groupId);

        foreach (UserGroup userGroup in userGroupService.GetByGroupId(productGroup.Id))
        {
            if (userGroup.EmailTracking)
                emails.Add(aspUserService.GetByUserId(userGroup.UserId).UserName);
        }

        return emails;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you were to do maintenance on an application you've never seen before, where would you expect it to be? Since it is something that "belongs" to a group, i think that putting it in the group-repo/service would be the right approach. In your example, i would suggest creating a new group-repository, extending the IRepository of group, and create a method for getting the group object, including the connection entities. When scaling your application, this will make a huge difference, since you wont have to query the database for every subobject (n+1 problem).

Answer (score 0):

No offense, but all your approaches suck for the following reasons: tight coupling and messing around responsibilities.

The generic repository is an anti pattern, stay away from it. Your first approach pretty much does the work of a repository and it's a static function (why?!).

The services shouldn't be coupled to concrete repositories. All dependencies should be injected as abstractions via constructor. I get the feeling that aspUsersService,GroupService and UserGroupService (what's the difference????) are actually implemented like a repository and thus, they are useless.

Actually from what I see, all your services are practically repositories. Cut the useless code, have one service/repository that uses directly EF and that's it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, sorry the method shouldn't be static is was a typo! I am using repositories and services (not just one for both) as in the future i may need to add more complex methods or validation and i want to only interact with the service classes not the generic repository directly from the client. I might be wrong but i don't think my service classes are coupled to concrete repositories, they accept an "IRepository<TEntity>" in the constructor.

Comment: I am trying to follow and approach as seen here http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef-5-using-mvc-4/implementing-the-repository-and-unit-of-work-patterns-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application. This is where i got the idea for a generic repository from. I also added a service layer on top of it for reasons explained in my earlier comment. Would you still advice i scrap the repository and handle everything via the service classes? Once again thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Generic repository is a very bad idea as it's defeats the purpose of the repository. Your service are coupled to concrete repository classes, instead of an abstraction. Since your services seems to do the work of a repository, just remove the middle man and use directly EF inside your service. It doesn't matter how an object is named (repo or service), it matters its behavour (and responsibility). Your repos right now are not doing anything useful as they return EF entities and NOT business objects. So cut them loose and have the service use directly EF =>

Comment: Your service implementation will reside in DAL but that shouldn't matter, since your app should depend on an abstraction (an interface) of the service (not the concrete type). And your service is designed for data access, it's not a business service. If it were, then its implementation would have been in th BL and it would take a repository or another service as dependency.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're a little confused between the point of repositories and service classes. Your service classes are just repositories. You ended up having to work this way because of the generic repository pattern. This pattern is actually an anti-pattern. It seems nice at first until you get to the point you're at. Instead you should create repositories for each of your entities that handle all CRUD operations for that entity. In these repositories is where you'll place your 'GetEmailTrackingAddressesGroup' type methods. And then your service layer can handle interacting with more that one repository if need be. Your service classes shouldn't have hard coded instances of your repositories. Instead you should be inject repository interfaces into your service's constructor.

Here's an example of how I would set up repositories and a simple service that interacts with 2 repositories.

```
public interface IUserRepository
{
    void Insert(User user);
    ...
    IEnumerable<User> GetByDepartmentId(int deptId);
}

public interface IContactLogRepository
{
    void Insert(ContactLog contactLog); 
}

public class EmailService
{
    private readonly IUserRepository _userRepo;
    private readonly IContactLogRepository _contactLogRepo;

    public EmailService(IUserRepository userRepo, IContactLogRepository contLogRepo) {
        _userRepo = userRepo;
        _contactLogRepo = contLogRepo;
    }

    public void EmailDepartment(int deptId, string message) {
        var employees = _userRepo.GetByDepartmentId(deptId);

        foreach (var emp in employees) {
            Email(emp.Email, message);

            _contactLogRepo.Insert(new ContactLog {
                EmployeeId = emp.Id,
                Message = message
            });
        }
    }

    private void Email(string address, string message) {
        ...
    }
}
```

So our repositories are there to handle CRUD operations for a specific entity - not our service layer. The generic repository pattern forces us to do CRUD (well at least the retrieval) in our services.